# sorting xml data by attributes using servlets

Tags: xml, servlets

I am very beginner to servlets.

I am trying to sort XML file by attributs.

My XML data contains userId,Name,Score. I want to sort by score attribute

Here is the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<Course>
 <User>
 <UserId>1</UserId>
 <FirstName>ABC</FirstName> 
<LastName>PQR</LastName> 
<Score>70</Score> 
</User> 
<User> 
<UserId>2</UserId> 
<FirstName>ABC1</FirstName>
 <LastName>PQR1</LastName> 
<Score>90</Score> 
</User> 
<User> 
<UserId>3</UserId> 
<FirstName>ABC2</FirstName> 
<LastName>PQR2</LastName> 
<Score>80</Score>
 </User>
 </Course>
```

And I want result data of userId 3, UserId 2, userId 1

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Course>
<User>
<UserId>1</UserId>
<FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
<LastName>PQR</LastName>
<Score>70</Score>
</User>
<User>
<UserId>2</UserId>
<FirstName>ABC1</FirstName>
<LastName>PQR1</LastName>
<Score>90</Score>
</User>
<User>
<UserId>3</UserId>
<FirstName>ABC2</FirstName>
<LastName>PQR2</LastName>
<Score>80</Score>
</User>
</Course>

Comment: "Servlet" is rather vague. That's a bit as if you said you're trying to do that with a programming language... Could you show what code you have so far and how does this XML come into it?

Comment: Actually I want data in sorted manner, Means I am calling function through Jquery AJAX, And I want responce in sorted manner with score

Comment: Sort the data first, and send the response then? I assume the XML is automatically serialized by whatever framework you use from some Java objects you send as a response. Of course I asked you to show your code so that there would be no need to assume anything, and we would just know instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this XSLT transformation (which you can easily invoke from the Java servlet code):

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Course>
   <xsl:for-each select="User">
     <xsl:sort select="Score" data-type="number"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Course>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```